# Modulus to account for negative numbers

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a code for modulus, but when I do it for negative numbers I don't get the right result, my code:

```
double mod (double X, double Y)
{
    double result = X;
    if (X>0){
    do
    {
      result =  result - Y;
    }while(result >= Y);
    }

    if (X<0){
    do
    {
      result =  result + Y;
        }while(0 >= result);
    }
}
```

When you do something like mod(-5,2) it should return -1 but it returns 1, why does it return 1 when it can't be greater than 0?

In my mind I thought it works like -5 + 2 = -3 + 2 = -1. For positive it would be 5 - 2 = 3 - 2 = 1.

Thanks.

EDIT: I am trying to do this without using CMATH using my own math library.

EDIT: My return result is in a later part of the program and does show output. This just a block of the entire program itself.

Comment: This is just an exercise and you're aware of `std::fmod`, right?

Comment: Why not just note the sign of X at the beginning of the function, and make the result match that sign when you return?

Comment: Well, you *could* add an `return result;` statement instead of writing second edit, right? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examine this part of code only:

```
if (X<0){
    do
    {
      result =  result + Y;
    }while(0 >= result);
}
```

Let's say that X is -5, and `result` is 0.

`do` loop will be executed:

```
1. pass - result = -3
2. pass - result = -1 
3. pass - result = -1 + 2 = 1
```

`3. pass` will be executed as result from `2. pass` is still less than zero.

You need to change your loop condition to `while(0 >= result + Y)`

Comment: This works, thank you for the explanation. What exactly is pass? Also what would I put for the while if X were positive and Y negative (5, -1)?

Comment: It is pass of the loop - first time, second time, and so on... About second question - I have no idea - it is almost 5AM here - and I still need to fix damn dangling else problem for my compilers course tomorrow :)

Comment: Well at least the first part is right, I think I can try and figure out the rest, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing

```
return result;
```

Comment: Hooray for compiler warnings that should always be turned on.

Answer (score 1):

consider the integer sequence

```
-7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

when taking `mod(5,2)` we are taking multiple of 2 less than or equal to 5 then return difference with 5. ie here `1 (5-4)`

for negative numbers according to this concept

for `mod(-5, 2)`. number which is lesser than -5 that is divisible by 2 is -6(not -4; -4 > -5). and its difference is `(-5 - -6)` which is `1`.
That is what happening in your code